# Web AppBuilder Developer Edition - on(someNode, "click", someFunction) Executes N Times When Widget Opened for the N-th Time

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have an `on(someNode, "click", someFunction)` in the `onOpen()` of `Widget.js`. The problem is that if the widget is closed then reopened (2nd open), the click event on `someNode` fires twice. If close and reopen the widget again (3rd open), the click event fires three times, so on and so forth...

Is there a way to let the click event on `someNode` only fire once after reopening the widget?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out with help from elsewhere: put the `on(someNode, "click", someFunction)` to `postCreate()` instead of `onOpen()` so that no new event listener is added everytime widget if opened.